# Google Chrome force reload for angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I am using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to force a reload in Google Chrome when I change my angular views html but with angular ui-view tag my partials still with old cache why?

Comment: Try this: open chrome dev tools, network tab, then check "Disable cache"

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with something like: cache:false in your routing definiton? like:

```
 $stateProvider
            .state("splash", {
                url: "/splash",
                abstract:true,
                templateUrl: "/app/view/template/splash/splash.html"
            })

            .state("index", {
                cache: true, //<-- THIS FORCE CACHE 
                abstract: true,
                url: "/index",
                templateUrl: "/app/view/template/common/content.html"
            })
```

if it is not enough try also in app.run() method something like:

```
 app.run([
        "$rootScope", "$templateCache", function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
            $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {

                    if (typeof (current) !== "undefined") {
                        $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl); //<-- CLEAN CACHE OF ANGULAR OF HTML TEMPLATE

                }

            });
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: i have already tried the cache but doesn't work, i gonna try with app run